# ¿Se puede resetar el id de la tabla con un trigger?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

es que tengo una tabla con varios registros y al momento de eliminar uno de ellos me gustaria que el id de la tabla se reseteara por medio de un tigger ya intente esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no me deja implementarlo y no se si realmente se pueda hacer por medio de un tigger

Comment: ese código por defecto resetea el valor del indice autoincrement a `MAX(id)+1` no a 1 ¿por qué? bueno esto es obvio, que pasa si en la tabla tienes el registro 1, 2 y 3, decides borrar el 1, reseteas el id y te manda a 1, agregas un registro (se agrega el 1) y luego agregas otro, este intentaría ingresar el 2 que ya existe entonces te mandará error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La única forma que yo conozco de resetear un id de una tabla es aplicándole TRUNCATE, el detalle de esta sentencia es que te va a vaciar la tabla y borrara los registros (Cosa que no queremos). En tal caso, si necesitas tener un orden para visualizar tus registros, te recomiendo que cuando hagas la lista del lado del cliente le pongas un contador en una de las columnas y listo, ya que el id de una tabla, es solo un numero para diferenciar un registro de otro.